# Instantiate object with abstract parameters

Tags: php, unit-testing, oop, automated-tests, phpunit

```
interface aInterface{
     public function __construct(aClass_Abstract $a, bClass_Abstract $b){
     }
}
class Sample implements aInterface
{
     public function __construct(aClass_Abstract $a, bClass_Abstract $b){
         //implementation
         $this->init();
     }
     public function init(){
         //implementation
     }
}
```

How to setup this on testing using PHPUnit?

...implementation...
test

```
...
function setUp(){
    //initialize
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In a Nutshell: Use [`getMockForAbstractClass`](http://www.phpunit.de/manual/3.5/en/test-doubles.html#test-doubles.mock-objects) to create a [**fake instance**](http://www.phpunit.de/manual/3.5/en/test-doubles.html#test-doubles) of the classes you need to pass in so you can test them.

```
$a = $this->getMockForAbstractClass("aClass_Abstract");
$b = $this->getMockForAbstractClass("bClass_Abstract");
$class = new Sample($a, $b);
```

### Full code example

(Fixed the interface definition)

```
<?php

interface aInterface{
     public function __construct(aClass_Abstract $a, bClass_Abstract $b);
}
class Sample implements aInterface
{
     public function __construct(aClass_Abstract $a, bClass_Abstract $b){
         //implementation
         $this->a = $a;
     }
     public function init(){
         return $this->a->myMethod();
     }
}

abstract class aClass_Abstract {
    abstract public function myMethod();
}

abstract class bClass_Abstract {}

class SampleTest extends PHPUnit_Framework_TestCase {

    public function testSetup() {

        $a = $this->getMockForAbstractClass("aClass_Abstract");
        $a->expects($this->once())->method("myMethod")->will($this->returnValue(true));
        $b = $this->getMockForAbstractClass("bClass_Abstract");
        $class = new Sample($a, $b);
        $this->assertTrue($class->init());

    }
}


/*
PHPUnit 3.5.12 by Sebastian Bergmann.

.

Time: 0 seconds, Memory: 3.25Mb
*/
```

Comment: Thans for the answers. It helped me a lot because I am new to unit testing.

Answer (score 2):

Assuming you want to test `Sample` you will be using [Stubs or Mocks](http://www.martinfowler.com/articles/mocksArentStubs.html#TheDifferenceBetweenMocksAndStubs):

```
class SampleTest extends PHPUnit_Framework_TestCase
{
    public function testSomething()
    {
        $stubA = $this->getMockForAbstractClass('aClass_Abstract');
        $stubA->expects($this->any())
              ->method('abstractMethod')
              ->will($this->returnValue(TRUE));

        // do the same for bClass_Abstract

        $sample = new Sample($stubA, $stubB);
        // add an assertion for sample
    }
}
```

Quoting the [PHPUnit Manual on `getMockForAbstractClass`](http://www.phpunit.de/manual/3.4/en/test-doubles.html#test-doubles.mock-objects):

> The `getMockForAbstractClass()` method returns a mock object for an abstract class. All abstract methods of the given abstract class are mocked. This allows for testing the concrete methods of an abstract class.

See that chapter for additional information on Test Doubles and [search StackOverflow for more information on Mocking with PHPUnit](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bphpunit%5D%20mock)

Answer (score 0):

You are probably looking for mock objects.

http://www.phpunit.de/manual/3.6/en/test-doubles.html

https://github.com/padraic/mockery